# What do these little triangles above the note mean for Euphonium/Trombone?

Tags: sheet-music

This was from a Complete Method For Trombone & Euphonium, by Joseph Alessi and Dr. Brian Bowmen. Called Arban. Page 17 of the book.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Aaron so is it staccatissimo? It's marked only on the first notes in each example, but I guess it's meant to be continued through the whole exercise? Perhaps that's explained in the text above?

Comment: @user1079505, i looked up staccatissimo, and it shows the symbol. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user1079505 Yes, in exercises like these, where there's a reasonably clear pattern,  markings are often just included at the beginning and then assumed elsewhere.